# Jdbc table design which is better

Tags: database, jdbc

Hi I'm creating a notification system which consists of only 3 data inputs
1. email - to which the notification should be sent
2. the notification message - varchar
3. status - sent or not (y or N)

--*Note the final goal is club all notification to be sent to an email and send it as one email by a batch job*

Help me choosing which design is better

**Design -1** 
create table Notifications(
notification_id integer auto_increment primary key,
message varchar(100) not null
);

create table Emails(
email_id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
email varchar(40) not null
);

create table Email_notifications(
email_id integer not null,
notification_id integer ,
status varchar(5) not null,

foreign key(email_id) references  Emails(email_id),
foreign key(notification_id) references Notifications(notification_id),
primary key(email_id, notification_id)
);

**Design-2:**

create table batchnotifications(
id integer not null auto_increment primary key,
email varchar(40) not null,
message varchar(100) not null,
status varchar(5) not null default 'N'
);

Since i'm going to use JDBC in it let me know in that perspective in terms of ease of api creation.

Comment: **Design-1** is better as it provide more clarity and flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **Design 1** Its better to implement.
you can use **Design-2** also but if you have to send status to multiple people with different emails and notifications,then it is possible only with **Design-1**
Let's assume one condition :
If you have to send email with id 2 and notification with id 4 then in that case, you need two different tables for email and notification. which you are doing in **Design-1**.
**AND**
Let's assume another condition :
If you have to send unique email and notification with same id then use **Design-2**

Comment: can you explain the second scenario little bit more

Comment: In **Design-2** you can use only fixed email with fixed notification for id 1, like : if you wish to use email id 2 and notification id 4 for first entry then you can't achieve this with **Design-2**. here you have to use fixed values for particular entry.

Comment: If you had gone through this then give it up vote so other people will get help

Comment: i have less than 15 reputation.. so it wont be taken into consideration

Comment: no its not anything like that, you can tick these answer so you will get 2 reputations. just tick on right mark below 1

Answer (score 0):

Design 1 is future proof.
Design 2 is still correct with respect of normalization rules, assuming that:

- you will not add later content like "Name", "Reputation", etc to the email. In that moment, usage of Design 1 is mandatory.
- the relative large key of "email" is not a space/performance problem, as compared to the integer key.

The driver you use to connect (JDBC, DAO, ODBC, OLEDB or native) is irrelevant with respect of the data structure.